# vue.js: hero background video with self hosting (local) video file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, video, background

What is the right way to create a `hero background video` in `vue.js`?

The following way doesn't work.

html:

```
<template>
    <div id="hero">
        <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="../assets/img/hero-1.jpg" id="bgvideo" width="1080" height="720">
            <source :src="videoUrl" :type="videoType">
        </video>
    </div>

</template>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'SectionHome',
    data() {
        return {
            videoUrl: '@/assets/videos/hero-1.mp4',
            videoType: 'video/mp4'
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

I also tried to pass the file path directly to the html tag: `<source src="@/assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">`, but according to [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2876) this way doesn't work at all. By the way I have the same problem with `vuetify` `<v-img ...>`, passing local files doesn't work, whereby `<img ...>` does work.

Comment: have you tried `<v-img :src="require('path to local file')">` for passing local files?

Comment: I think you can try the same with `<source>`

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? I m curious to know

Comment: For anybody wondering: This is working. @DjSh if you write an answer I'm happy to upvote

Comment: @StefanHaberl so <source :src="require..."> worked?

Comment: Yes,  `<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster='@/path/to/preview.jpg'><source :src='require("@/path/to/video.mp4")' type='video/mp4'></video>` actually works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve passing local files in Vuetify you just need to add `require` to your `src`

From Vuetify :

> Vue loader converts relative paths into require functions automatically for you. Unfortunately, this is not the case when it comes to **custom components**. You can circumvent this issue by using require. If you're using Vuetify as a Vue-CLI 3 plugin, you can edit your project's vue.config.js file by modifying the options for vue-loader.

Incorrect
   `<v-img src="../path/to/img" />`

Correct
   `<v-img :src="require('../path/to/img')" />`

You can also do the same with `<source :src="require('@/path/to/video')">`

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster='@/assets/img/hero-1.jpg'>
    <source :src='require("@/assets/videos/hero-1.mp4")' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```